# How to increase Firefox scrollbar width?

Tags: firefox, gui

On my system (I am just running Fluxbox 1.3.7 on FreeBSD 10.3 – but I've seen that on Linux, too) Firefox has a much more narrow scrollbar than on Windows (which also behaves differently).

[image: narrow Firefox scrollbar on Linux]

How do I increase the width of the scrollbar?

It would also be nice to get the usual behavior, i.e. clicking on the scrollbar should move the scrollbox *just one step* up or down and not position it where I clicked.

**EDIT:** Installing [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/) solves the problem (in a not very elegant way). The scrollbar looks ridiculous now, but at least it has a nice width. ;-)

Comment: Not confident it will work with Firefox but you may try to add `*Scrollbar*width: 16` to your `~/.Xresources` and then source it with `xrdb .Xresources`.  (will affect new instances of windows not already running instances)

Comment: @grochmal: sadly, this has absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `about:config`, set `widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size.override` to the desired numeric value.

This will only have an effect if `widget.non-native-theme.enabled` is `true` (the default as of this writing). Older versions may instead have the setting named `widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size`.

Comment: This doesn't work in 91.5

Comment: This works with FF 105. I set mine to 40. Tiny-Elvis says, 'It's huge.'  ;)

Comment: This works great, but when you grab a slider you cannot pull it down unless you follow the original narrow gutter. Does anyone know if there is a setting to fix that?

Comment: Answering my own question above, the slider works fine after restart.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, and causes an obstruction, especially if one chooses to enclose a caption using two tick symbols, ``, in a reddit post. I also had difficulty closing the eBay notification (bell icon).

Answer (score 7):

Ignom's answer is correct, but as of version 89 Firefox no longer honors GTK styling by default. The new setting in about:config `widget.non-native-theme.enabled` needs to be changed to `false`.

(I would have made this a comment on Ignom's answer, but I don't have enough rep.)

Comment: This was very helpful, but for me it changed the color of the scrollbar and now it no longer matches the GTK theme's color.  Do you happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: For the color, I had to use `about:config` to change `widget.content.gtk-theme-override` to `Ambiance`.

Answer (score 2):

Running Alma linux with firefox version 91.8.0:

This is what worked for me:
Enter about:config in browser bar, type in 'scrollbar' to filter:

Find:
widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size

And change the value to what you want. *restart firefox for changes to take effect*
I set mine to 40 - now clicking the bar is like clicking the side of a barn

Comment: This seems to be the same as [Jarek's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653105/80216).

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways to increase the Firefox scrollbar width (tested with Firefox 68.9esr and FreeBSD 12.1):

1. Tune GTK3 style settings
   Firefox is using GTK3. So you can override relevant settings of the GTK3 style you are using. You find the style settings in `/usr/local/share/themes/<your style>/gtk-3.20/gtk.css`. To override some of the settings use the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.
   A setup you can use to start your own experiments can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1272428/how-do-you-configure-the-appearance-of-scrollbars-in-firefox-57/1273053#1273053).
2. Use CSS
   Newer Firefox versions allow to use CSS to change the way Firefox displays the GUI (see [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserContent.css&printable=yes) for details).
   You need to use the file `userContent.css` in the subdirectory `chrome` of your profile folder. With the setting `scrollbar-width: auto;` you can increase the Firefox scrollbar width (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) for a description).
   [Here](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx) you can find an easy to handle project to tweak a lot of the Firefox GUI CSS settings, including the scrollbar width (update the settings in `./config/custom_scrollbar_appearance.css` and enable its import in your `userContent.css`).
   Please note, that with newer Firefox versions config settings may prohibit this mechanism (e.g. see `about:config` preference `layout.css.scrollbar-width.enabled`).
   Please note further, that if you specify scrollbar relevant settings via CSS, then the GTK3 settings via `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` are ignored.

With the CSS approach it is currently not possible to specify the exact width of the scrollbar. With GTK3 tuning this is possible and you can also set additional scrollbar properties.